# How one can get $1.96$ Standard Deviation for 95% Confidence Interval?

Tags: confidence-interval, standard-deviation

I have been trying hard to understand that how the highlighted $1.96$ standard deviation is calculated. Please help.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $Y = \sum_{i=1}^{100} X_i$, then we have $Y \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ approximately by CLT.

We want to choose $k$ such that

$$Pr(\mu-k\sigma \le Y \le \mu \le \mu+k\sigma)=0.95$$

$$Pr(-k \le \frac{Y-\mu}{\sigma}\le k)=0.95$$

We know that $Z=\frac{Y-\mu}{\sigma}$ follows $N(0,1)$.

Hence we can read for the corresponding quartile value and find that it is equal to $1.96$.

Notice that $Pr(Z \le 1.96)=0.975$ and $Pr(Z \le -1.96) =0.025$.

$$Pr(-1.96 \le Z \le 1.96)=1-Pr(Z > 1.96)-Pr(Z < -1.96)=0.95$$

Comment: Thank you so much!